# Should we store an auto-increment ID when we have a unique indexed column

Tags: mysql

I am designing a MySQL data table to store e-business orders,each order has an unique order number looks like '20160223xxxxxx',it is generated by a specified algorithm to ensure it is unique in the table. I am wondering if we still need an auto-increment field as primary key in the table since I think the order number seems also can be the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not *need* an auto-incremented id, because you have one.  However, I am a big fan of synthetic primary keys:

- They define a sequence for the inserts, so you know what rows were most efficient.
- 4-byte integers (if your table is not really big) is more efficient for foreign key indexes than longer character strings.
- If one of the unique order ids changes, a synthetic primary key makes it easy to change the value.
- You are isolated from future changes in the order-key-generating system.
- If you mysql the primary key is generally the clustered index.  Hence, inserts with a synthetic key go to the end of the table -- which is efficient.  Inserts with an outside key might be out-of-order -- which is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an auto-inc field. Use the unique identifier as the PK of the table. It will save space.